# Using await Task inside backgroundWorker is changing my status to complete

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am using a loop each 7 seconds. This loop communicates with a server. Then when server is answering i am waiting user to answer about servers response. So i need to check if all this process has finished.
So i am creating a timer

```
var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender, e) => backgroundWorker_DoWork(sender, e, frm);

var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Interval = 10000;
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Timer_Elapsed(sender, e);
timer.Start();

 private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
    if (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
    {
      backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
  }

private static async void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e, Main frm)
{
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      var result = await client.GetAsync(uri);
      //message to user for answering, then return it to server again
   }
 }
```

For some reason when i am using await..., 'backgroundWorker.IsBusy' flag turns to false. I mean that i can't have correct result if task has actually finished. Should i use a flag for this? or there is more efficient way?

Comment: Pick one to do your work, you don't need both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `await` inside a `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork`. I recommend [replacing `BackgroundWoker` completely with `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html):

```
Task task = null;

var timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 10000;
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
timer.Start();

private static async void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (task == null)
  {
    task = Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(frm));
    try { await task; }
    finally { task = null; }
  }
}

private static async Task DoWorkAsync(Main frm)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var result = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    //message to user for answering, then return it to server again
  }
}
```

Side note: I changed `System.Timers.Timer` to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` so that the `task` variable is always accessed from the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will follow your method. Is System.Windows.Forms.Timer better than System.Timers.Timer? I mean for performance reasons i dont need to run my task inui thread until user will accept the answer on server

Comment: @JohnPapadopoulos: It's not better - just different. E.g., `System.Timers.Timer` will run its `Elapsed` event on a thread pool thread, and `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` will run its `Tick` event on the UI thread.

Comment: Are they have any difference in performance? Which of two are you prefer for my example?

Comment: I also read your blog Task.Run vs BackgroundWorker. You are incredible!!!

Comment: @JohnPapadopoulos: The performance difference is minimal except for situations where the UI thread is busy doing other things, in which case the `Forms.Timer` can be delayed (waiting for the UI thread to be free). For your example, I'd recommend `Forms.Timer` unless its performance is unacceptable.